# how to get all items with same values in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json with some characters, and need to print all characters with 3 stars (example)
but how?
json example:

```json
[
        {
            "name":"Naruto Uzumaki",
            "anime":"Naruto",
            "star":"2",
            "ID":0
        },
        {
            "name":"Son Goku",
            "anime":"Dragon Ball",
            "star":"3",
            "ID":1
        },
        {
            "name":"Monkey D. Luffy",
            "anime":"One Piece",
            "star":"2",
            "ID":2

        },
        {
            "name":"Naruto Uzumaki (Sage Mode)",
            "anime":"Naruto",
            "star":"3",
            "ID":3
        }
]
```

I'm looking for a method to print them all, and be able to randomize between them too
like:

```js
console.log(unit)//{"name":"son Goku"....},{"name":"Naruto"....}
random = 0;
unit = unit[random]
console.log(unit)//{"name":"son Goku"....}
```

Comment: Can you provide more info about what you mean by randomize?

Comment: just get the length of array (of the characters that only have 3 stars, i this case, 2. values 0 and 1 in array) and get the person data in array with that number.

Comment: so randomize array data to print
(dont modify array, just get a random data from this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use The `filter()` method to create a new array with your condition from your previous array.

```
const formatedara = data.filter(x => x.star === "3");
```

From this new array, you can get any specific object by -

```
formatedara[index];
```

```js
const data = [{
    name: "Naruto Uzumaki",
    anime: "Naruto",
    star: "2",
    ID: 0,
  },
  {
    name: "Son Goku",
    anime: "Dragon Ball",
    star: "3",
    ID: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "Monkey D. Luffy",
    anime: "One Piece",
    star: "2",
    ID: 2,
  },
  {
    name: "Naruto Uzumaki (Sage Mode)",
    anime: "Naruto",
    star: "3",
    ID: 3,
  },
];

const formatData = data.filter((x) => x.star === "3");
console.log(formatData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `array.map(x => x.star === "3")` method. That will create a new array with the items that correspond to your parameters. Also, you're storing the star number as a string, which is not ideal if you want to do maths with it later.

Answer (score 0):

do u want like this ?

```
unit.forEach((e)=>{
            if (e.star == "3") {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
                //do sth
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var objJson = JSON.parse('[{"name": "Naruto Uzumaki","anime": "Naruto","star": "2", "ID": 0}, { "name": "Son Goku","anime": "Dragon Ball","star": "3","ID": 1 }, {"name": "Monkey D. Luffy", "anime": "One Piece","star": "2","ID": 2},{"name": "Naruto Uzumaki (Sage Mode)","anime": "Naruto","star": "3","ID": 3}]');
        
var filteredJson = objJson.filter(x => x.star === "3");

console.log(filteredJson);

var random = 0;
filteredJson = filteredJson[random]

console.log(filteredJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use basic methods also but better is using filter method.

```
var array = [];

for(i = 0; i < sample.length; i++) {
  if (sample[i].star === "3") {
    array.push(sample[i]);
  }
}

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

> print all characters with 3 stars (example) but how
> for a method to print them all, and be able to randomize between them too like

Just split your problem in multiple steps and it will become clear.

1. Get characters with 3 stars.
2. Print characters.
3. Get a random character from a set of characters.

```js
const characters = [
        {
            "name":"Naruto Uzumaki",
            "anime":"Naruto",
            "star":"2",
            "ID":0
        },
        {
            "name":"Son Goku",
            "anime":"Dragon Ball",
            "star":"3",
            "ID":1
        },
        {
            "name":"Monkey D. Luffy",
            "anime":"One Piece",
            "star":"2",
            "ID":2

        },
        {
            "name":"Naruto Uzumaki (Sage Mode)",
            "anime":"Naruto",
            "star":"3",
            "ID":3
        }
];


// Find all with 3 stars
const threeStarChars = characters.filter(hasTreeStar);

// Print those characters
threeStarChars.forEach(printCharacter);

// Randomize characters
const random3StarCharacter = randomSequenceOf(threeStarChars);
const anyRandomCharacter = randomSequenceOf(characters);

document.querySelector('button:first-child').addEventListener('click', () => printCharacter(random3StarCharacter()));

document.querySelector('button:nth-child(2)').addEventListener('click', () => printCharacter(anyRandomCharacter()));


function hasTreeStar(character) {
    return character.star === '3';
}

function printCharacter(character) {
    // Some printing logic
    console.log(JSON.stringify(character, null, 4));
}

function randomSequenceOf(items) {
    const all = [...items];
    const current = [...items];
    
    return function () {
        if (!current.length) current.push(...items);
        return current.splice(randomBetween(0, current.length), 1).pop();
    };
}

function randomBetween(min, max) { 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

```html
<button>Print random 3 star</button>
<button>Print any random</button>
```